# cannot find the declaration of attribute 'object' in SingleObjectMixin

Tags: django, django-views

I checked the source code of SingleObjectMxin but there is no definition of attribute `object`. How this piece code in `get_context_data()` works?

```
if self.object:  
    context['object'] = self.object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's set in `BaseDetailView.get` and returned from `get_object`. (~15 lines further down in `detail.py`)

Comment: ok, thank you. so python allows us to define the instance attributes outside of `__init__`?

Comment: Yes. One of the reasons it's so powerful yet concise.